# Vector Space Axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am having trouble understanding vector space axioms seen here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6VBD.jpg). As an example say we define our potential vector space to be the set of all pairs of real numbers of the form $(x, 0)$ with the standard operations on $\mathbb R^2$. What would $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ be in this example? How would I go about testing if this potential vector space is indeed a vector space? Any help  would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your set is the vectors of the form $(x, 0)$. Just take two vectors $(a, 0), (b, 0)$ and a real number, say $c$, and test if the axioms hold. For example, for the first one, $(a, 0) + (b, 0) = (a+b, o)$. This is in the space, since it is on the form $(x, 0)$ and $a+b \in \mathbb{R}$, so the first axiom holds.

Comment: So say for axiom #10 (1u = u) I could say 1(a,0) = (a,0) and it would also hold? From what I can tell they all hold.

Comment: @FAYNUS You may want to write it as $1*(a, 0) = (1*a, 0) = (a, 0)$, just to show all the steps, but yes. They all should hold, but this type of question means that you have to write out all the details to check each axiom.